# MySQL is very slow on an indexed table, but a copy of the table is fast

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam

I have a `MyISAM` table with > 20 million records. I perform a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE group = 123;
```

which takes about 2 seconds. I made a copy of the table, and here the same query takes 0.02 seconds.

I used `HeidiSQL` to perform the query and it returns a status message

> Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 685  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.016 sec. (+ 2.266 sec. network)

On the copied table, I find the same message, but with `+ 0.016 sec. network`.

What is causing the huge delay on the original table? How to optimize the performance? I ran an `OPTIMIZE TABLE data` query, but this does not have any effect.

Comment: MyISAM does not handle concurrent read/writes, so this could be the cause. Please enable profiling and post the result of SHOW PROFILE for both queries. Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

Comment: Is the Query Cache turned on?  Next time you see `xx Warnings`, promptly do `SHOW WARNINGS;`.  Is there an index on `group`?

Comment: First step to optimize a query is to run an explain, i.e. Put `EXPLAIN` before `SELECT` and study the result.